# Plot Isochrones with folium or similar

Tags: python, plot, geospatial, folium

I have reachability  data from a given source S. S is a coordinate [latitude, longitude].

The reachability data are a list of coordinates together with the distance in minutes from S: each element of the list E is [lat, lon, minutes].

Now I would like to build an isochrone map using these data, where each range depend on the minutes, e.g., we can divide each zone of 60 minutes.

I tried using openrouteservice for python, but it has already ad-hoc functions to retrieve nearby points given a source.  I would like to have only some modality, in Folium or other frameworks, in which I put a source, all the destination in some format with the minutes needed to reach them, and plot the map.